# Generate all combinations of slice - design of experiment in Go

Tags: go, combinations

I have the following levels in a design of experiment.

```
levels := []int{0, 5, 10} // three levels
```

The factors are as follows:

```
factors := []int{6, 21, 7, 8, 32} // five factors
```

The important thing is that there are Nf factors. Number of experiments is therefore:

```
n := math.Pow(float64(3), float64(Nf)) // = 243
```

I need to generate all possible 243 combos as follows:

```
1: {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
2: {0, 0, 0, 0, 5}
3: {0, 0, 0, 0, 10}
4: {0, 0, 0, 5, 0}
5: {0, 0, 0, 5, 5}
6: {0, 0, 0, 5, 10}
7: {0, 0, 0, 10, 0}
...
243: {10, 10, 10, 10, 10}
```

How do I go about doing this in a generic function **in Go**, knowing that the number of factors can be variable?

Comment: So, it's a standard algorithm to generate combinations? It's commonly solved with backtracking: https://the-algorithms.com/algorithm/all-combinations

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Volker. yes that's a fair comment. I posted an answer which shows what I have working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution (Cartesian product) that works, using the Gonum package.
Here below the code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "gonum.org/v1/gonum/stat/combin"
) 

factors := []int{3, 3, 3, 3, 3} // three levels for each factor.

list := combin.Cartesian(factors)
    for i, v := range list {
        fmt.Println(i, v)
}
```

which returns the index for each level:

```
0 [0 0 0 0 0]
1 [0 0 0 0 1]
...
240 [2 2 2 2 0]
241 [2 2 2 2 1]
242 [2 2 2 2 2]
```

So if someone has a better way of doing this using the standard lib, please let me know.